# about python matrix logical indexing

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I'm newbie in python and I don't understand the following code;
I expected that test1 and test2 give me same results (8, the sum of second row), instead

```
a=np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,3, 4]])
b=np.matrix([[0,1]])
print(np.where(b==1))
test1=a[np.nonzero(b==1),:]
print(test1.sum())
ind,_=np.nonzero(b==1);  #found in a code that I'm trying to undestand (why the _ ?)

test2=a[ind,:]
print(test2.sum())
```

gives me

```
 (array([0]), array([1]))
 14
 6
```

in the first case I have the sum of the full matrix, in the second case I have the sum of the first row (instead of the 2nd)

I don't understand why this behavior

Comment: `nonzero` returns a tuple, so in the first case you are slicing using a tuple. In the second example `_` is used as a throwaway/placeholder variable (you'll find answers here on SO about that), so you are slicing using just the first element of the tuple returned by `nonzero`, hence the difference in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [869]: a
Out[869]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 3, 4]])
In [870]: b
Out[870]: matrix([[0, 1]])
```

In this use `where` is the same as `nonzero`:

```
In [871]: np.where(b==1)
Out[871]: (array([0], dtype=int32), array([1], dtype=int32))
In [872]: np.nonzero(b==1)
Out[872]: (array([0], dtype=int32), array([1], dtype=int32))
```

It gives a tuple, one indexing array for each dimension (2 for an `np.matrix`).  The `ind,_=` just unpacks those arrays, and throws away the 2nd.  `_` is reused in an interactive session such as the one I'm using.

```
In [873]: ind,_ =np.nonzero(b==1)
In [874]: ind
Out[874]: array([0], dtype=int32)
```

Selecting with `where` returns (0,1) value from `a`.  But is that what you want?

```
In [875]: a[np.where(b==1)]
Out[875]: matrix([[2]])
```

Adding the `:` does index the whole array, but with an added dimension; again probably not what we want

```
In [876]: a[np.where(b==1),:]
Out[876]: 
matrix([[[1, 2, 3]],

        [[1, 3, 4]]])
```

`ind` is a single indexing array, and so selects the 0's row from `a`.

```
In [877]: a[ind,:]
Out[877]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
In [878]:
```

But is the `b==1` supposed to find the 2nd element of `b`, and then select the 2nd row of `a`?  To do that we have to use the 2nd indexing array from `where`:

```
In [878]: a[np.where(b==1)[1],:]
Out[878]: matrix([[1, 3, 4]])
```

Or the 2nd column from `a` corresponding to the 2nd column of `b`

```
In [881]: a[:,np.where(b==1)[1]]
Out[881]: 
matrix([[2],
        [3]])
```

Because `a` and `b` are `np.matrix`, the indexing result is always 2d.

For `c` array, the `where` produces a single element tuple

```
In [882]: c=np.array([0,1])
In [883]: np.where(c==1)
Out[883]: (array([1], dtype=int32),)
In [884]: a[_,:]                # here _ is the last result, Out[883]
Out[884]: matrix([[1, 3, 4]])
```

We generally advise using `np.array` to construct new arrays, even 2d.  `np.matrix` is a convenience for wayward MATLAB users, and often confuses new `numpy` users.